# Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.Remoting namespace gone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a sample from this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples) and noticed after I imported it that Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.Remoting namespace is missing. I tried to search it via NuGet and I can't find it. Anyone got a clue? Or does this namespace already deleted from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason for this is usually because the Windows SDK was not or was imported incorrectly. You need to add Windows SDK 18362+.**

If even this doesn't work, try the following:

1. Restart your computer.
2. Delete the old Build/UWP folder.
3. Delete Unity's "Library" folder (under "Your Project/Library").
4. Re-open Unity and try to rebuild.